# Sub-query to make use of different distinct & orderby

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I need to use different order_by & distinct values, and I have made an attempt using a subquery.

How can I achieve this?

Could a qset select the Products I want, and then in a separate query, select the 15 Variations whose price you want to display?

In other words: Qset randomly selects product ID's (in a queryset), then python tells it to return a queryset of just those 15 items.

Speeding up the query too is important- as it takes ~800ms (when I order_by the pk) or 5.8seconds when I use order_by '?'.

My attempt:

```
    distinct_qs = (
        Product.objects
        .distinct('id')
    )

    qset = (
        Product.objects
        .filter(pk__in=distinct_qs)
        .order_by('rating', '?')
        .values('name', 'image',)
        .annotate(
            price=F('variation__price__price'),
            id=F('pk'),
            vari=F('variation'),
        )[:15]
    )
```

Sample of output data:

```
{"name":"Test Item","vari":10, id":1, "price":"80", "image":"xyz.com/1.jpg"},
{"name":"Test Item","vari":11, id":1, "price":"80", "image":"xyz.com/1.jpg"},
{"name":"Another one","vari":14, id":2, "price":"10", "image":"xyz.com/2.jpg"},
{"name":"Another one","vari":15, id":2, "price":"10", "image":"xyz.com/2.jpg"},
{"name":"And Again","vari":17, id":3, "price":"12", "image":"xyz.com/3.jpg"},
{"name":"And Again","vari":18, id":3, "price":"12", "image":"xyz.com/3.jpg"},
```

Desired output data:

```
{"name":"Test Item","vari":13, id":1, "price":"80", "image":"xyz.com/1.jpg"},
{"name":"Another one","vari":14, id":2, "price":"10", "image":"xyz.com/2.jpg"},
{"name":"And Again","vari":17, id":3, "price":"12", "image":"xyz.com/3.jpg"},
```

Sample of models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=400)
    ...

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    ...

class Image(models.Model):
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=540, blank=True, null=True)


class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: Please include db schema, sample data and desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I have added to my question. Thanks

Comment: I didn't work in python but in sql you can use Row_number() function. using this function you can specify the order of row number in over clause.

Comment: Please give me an example of this

Comment: Based on your models, there can be more than one images /prices for a Variation. Is this intentional? If yes, then what do you expect the products to be annotated with? Because, if variation has more than one prices then your product will get annotated with all those prices.

Comment: Yes- it will have multiple prices/images. I just want to to return the most recently created one (they all have a field called 'created')

Comment: You can use subquery - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24218#comment:11

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a custom model manager (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/ ) and create a method there which you then would use for returning variations instead of a standard query.

For randomising you could do like this:
select the last id of Variation (or Product), then generate different random 15 ids from that interval and then just pull objects with those ids from database. I think it should work faster.